# Windows Phone Youtube Download

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, download, youtube

I found a good Code Snippet for Downloading Youtube Files with C# .net.
http://sourcecodecenter.blogspot.com/2011/05/download-youtube-videos-with-c.html
I also tried this code on Windows Phone but the classes `HtmlAgilityPack, HtmlDocument and HtmlNode` aren't there. Anyway:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url); 
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

isn't working. There aren't a lot of lines not working as you can see...

I don't know the right windows phone classes for that.

Comment: You should try to find out what each class does and then find/write its Phone equivalent. This is too broad. SO is not a place to ask others to write your code.

Comment: I'm only a beginner in Windows Phone and I tried to find the equivalents but it's too difficult for a beginner. That's why I ask for help and I think 4 lines of code are already enough to replace the unknown classes. That's not asking others to write my code.

Comment: `HtmlAgilityPack` is an open-source library: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ If a class "isn't there", you should Google the name. More often that not, you'll get the class information and documentation on how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- HtmlAgilityPack - To use this on Windows Phone 7, you need to check out the folder named HAPPhone or HAPPhone7.1 from [CodePlex](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/94773) and then build it your self
- WebRequest - In silverlight, you need to get the response asynchronously. An example can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(VS.95).aspx